# Read how many Python instructions have been interpreted?

Tags: python

Is there a way to read how many Python virtual machine instructions have been interpreted since the virtual machine started?  I realise this may (if possible at all) only be applicable to CPython.

Comment: What do you mean by instruction? Lines of code? Function calls? This is high level language not an assembler after all.

Comment: @JarosławJaryszew: I guess VM instructions. I recall profiling Prolog programs by counting such instructions, which was very useful.

Comment: (It's interesting to note what a Google search for "cpython count instructions turns up at fourth position: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holy_Hand_Grenade_of_Antioch)

Comment: Related: http://www.quora.com/Python-programming-language-1/Is-there-any-way-to-make-the-Python-interpreter-count-the-number-of-opcodes-interpreted

Comment: @FabienAndre, quora, the evil android brother of SO. :)

Comment: I just noticed that my answer is basically the same as the one in the quora link.  Should have checked the comments before answering :-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not easily.  The canonical way to measure performance is to use [one of the profiling modules available](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/debug.html).  Still...

In CPython 2, it is possible to get an approximate measurement, for the current thread, from an extension module (i.e. C code) by reading the `PyThreadState` structure.  There is a field called `tick_counter` which, when multiplied by the *check interval*, it results in the number of bytecode instructions executed.  Or, in other words, the number of iterations of the interpreter main loop.

But as the check interval may change during the execution, this value is not precise.

Interesting links for CPython 2.7.4:

- http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/026ee0057e2d/Include/pystate.h#l83
- http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/026ee0057e2d/Python/ceval.c#l977
- http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sys.html#sys.setcheckinterval
- http://docs.python.org/2.7/c-api/init.html#PyThreadState_Get

Since CPython 3.2 the `tick_counter` lost its real meaning, so you're forced to use the tracing or profiling already mentioned:

- http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/a222a015e28d/Include/pystate.h#l98

Comment: Can the number of bytecode instructions ever decrease as measured with this technique?

Comment: I guess it depends on the platform (compiler + arquitecture combination).  As the `tick_counter` only increases, in very long running programs it will overflow and, most likely, wrap around.  And, because it is a signed integer, it will eventually become negative.